# PROBLEMA Serie Fibonacci como cadena de bits

Tags: c, recursión, fibonacci

Hola tengo un problema con ejercicio planteado en la imagen esta planteado para el **Lenguaje C**, no entiendo como lograr que la serie de forme únicamente con los valores de 0 y 1, espero que alguien tenga una idea de como se podría desarrollar y me pueda ayudar, se los agradezco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento este es el codigo que tengo

Comment: Ayudaría que subieras el código de lo que llevas de progreso. : )

Comment: Bienvenida, agrega lo que haz realizado , revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Por favor añade el código como texto.

Comment: El truco es encontrar la respuesta sin calcular una cadena muy larga fib(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu código, hacer los dos `strcat()` con `fibNuevo` a `fib0` y `fib1` es algo innecesario, algo que si considero necesario es definir una variable auxiliar. Esto ya que para realizar ese proceso de `nNuevo = n - 1 + n - 2` es necesario hacerle `strcpy()` a la auxiliar, para que cuando se concatene `fib1` con `fib0` todavía tener el valor original de `fib1` en nuestra ejecución. Mi propuesta de solución es implementar en el código esta variable auxiliar, y el ciclo `for` realizar dos copias (una de "respaldo") y una sola concatenación. Adjunto el código:

```
for (int i = 0;i < n - 1;i = i +1) {
    strcpy(fibAux,fib1);

    strcat(fib1,fib0);
    strcpy(fib0,fibAux);
}
```

**Nota:** Aquí el limite del `for` es `n` (el valor ingresado) menos 1, con el fin de no realizar una última copia/concatenación (por que los valores F(0) y F(1) ya están definidos en variables).

El código entero quedaría así:

**Solución:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

void fibonacci(int n) {
    char fib0[MAX] = "0";
    char fib1[MAX] = "1";
    char fibAux[MAX];

    for (int i = 0;i < n - 1;i = i +1) {
        strcpy(fibAux,fib1);

        strcat(fib1,fib0);
        strcpy(fib0,fibAux);
    }

    printf("%s \n",fib1);
}

int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("Digite el número de la secuencia: \n");
    scanf("%i",&n);

    if (n == 0) {
        printf("0 \n");
    } else {
        fibonacci(n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Otra nota:** Aquí se usaría la constante `MAX`, de longitud 100 (la secuencia tiene límite de 100 caracteres), sin embargo esto se puede modificar a gusto.

El condicional dentro del `main()` es para evitar que cuando se ingrese 0 se muestre por pantalla 1 (efecto del ejecutar la función `fibonacci()`). F(0) no es 1, es 0.

**Resultados:**

Una vez el programa compilado y en ejecución, da los siguientes resultados para las siguientes entradas:

**#1, 0:**

```
Digite el n├║mero de la secuencia:
0
0
```

**#2, 4:**

```
Digite el n├║mero de la secuencia:
4
10110
```

**#3, 6:**

```
Digite el n├║mero de la secuencia:
6
1011010110110
```

**#4, 10:**

```
Digite el n├║mero de la secuencia:
10
10110101101101011010110110101101101011010110110101101011011010110110101101011011010110110
```

Concordando con las salidas esperadas de la imagen que adjuntaste :)

**PD:** Perdón por esos caracteres medio raros, se suponía que eran us tiltadas (ú) xDxD

Espero que te haya servido, saludos!

Comment: Gracias gabrielcoronel voy a implementar en mi codigo.

Comment: El programa debe tener *dos* entradas (un patrón de bits "p" y un número "n") y imprimir un *número* de ocurrencias de "p" en "fib(n)".

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. cierto, fue mi error por no leer bien. Gracias por corregirme.

Comment: El problema aquí es F(n) se vuelve muy largo muy rápido. F(40) es demasiado largo para caber en 100,000,000 bits. F(90) no cabe en tu ordenador. `#define MAX 100`... no suficiente para nada.

Comment: El problema en realidad es que el objetivo de mi algoritmo era otro al del problema planteado, definí esa constante como ejemplo, estoy se guro que si cabe en mi ordenado es solo cambiar el valor de constante (como digo, la definí para dar el ejemplo).

Comment: De todos modos, la solución al problema ahora es más clara. Si se añade otra función que pida una secuencia de bits y se hace una comparación de fragmentos de F(n) con la secuencia indicada, ya es trabajo hecho.